# Google Compute Persistent Disk pricing

Tags: google-app-engine

I just want to ask how the pricing for GCE persistent disks work? Does it work the same as Azure where if I create a 1TB disk and store 10GB on it, I'm only charged for 10GB?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to ask how the pricing for GCE persistent disks work?

See detail explain here : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks

Does it work the same as Azure where if I create a 1TB disk and store 10GB on it, I'm only charged for 10GB?

No you need to pay all 1TB

Comment: Thanks Bui, though I saw that irs very easy to resize a disk from a snapshot. Will check for the link and add it later